# Javascript variable ESRI api

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currenty working with ESRI API and what I am trying to do is when user insert id of portal page, div will refresh and load a new map.

Where I am stuck, variable which I am using change but changes did not show up

```js
var konj = "9f91f911f58540ceaac0300c55e18fbb"//portal reference
 $(function(){
  $("#buto").click(function(){
   var bista = $("#inputField").val();
   window.konj = bista;
  });
 });


var map = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
          id: konj
        }
      });
      
 var mapView = new MapView({
        container: "mapViewDiv",
        map: map,
        padding: {
          top: 50,
          bottom: 0
        },
        ui: {components: []}
      });
```

```html
<div class="calcite-map calcite-map-absolute">
    <div id="mapViewDiv"></div>
  </div>
  
  
<!-- Form -->

<form id="nameForm">
  <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Please paste Id of map</label>
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
   <div class="col-auto">
     <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Id of map</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputField">
     <br>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buto">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

If I type in console log variable name it is changed. But changes does not applied.

Comment: Did you add the link to jquery?

Comment: Yes, of course. And variable is changing in console log after submit button. But it is not aplied. Nothing happens even variable is changed. :(

Comment: The variable `konj` is passed to the WebMap constructor when it is instantiated, but your click event listener is not passing the new value to the map. You need to provide the map with the new value.. The api might have an update method or alternatively you will need to create a new map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I come across this and forgot to put answer. This is how I solve it. Where mile in the end is assigned as mile1 so same function can work for new url over and over.

```js
$("#buto").click(function(){
   var bista = $("#inputField").val();
   window.konj = bista;
   map.remove(mile);
   mile = new FeatureLayer({
   url:bista
   });
   map.add(mile);
   });
  });
```